# loading data from firebase depending on which user is logged in

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I get the userID into the firebase url. I currently get this error... "use of unresolved identifier".

I tried moving the "let defaults: ..." and "let userID: ..." above the "let firebase = Firebase(url: ..)" but then got this error... "Instance member 'defaults' cannot be used on type TableViewController".

What I am trying to do is load a user profile of the user that matches the userID.

Relevant code below.

```
let firebase = Firebase(url:"https://<myfirebase>.firebaseio.com/users/\(userID)")
var items = [NSDictionary]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let rightItemBtn = UIButton()
    rightItemBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    rightItemBtn.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 60, 35)


    let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let userID = (defaults.objectForKey("userID") as? String)!

    let labelText = userID

    label.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 50, 35)

    label.text = labelText
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are trying to load in some user information for the currently authenticated user (?)

given a structure of

```
users
  uid_0:
   user_name: "Buzz Aldrin"
```

If so, it's super simple:

```
let fb = Firebase(url:"https://<myfirebase>.firebaseio.com")

let uid = fb.authData.uid
let usersRef = fb.childByAppendingPath("users")
let thisUserRef = usersRef.childByAppendingPath(uid)

thisUserRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
      let userName = snapshot.value.objectForKey("user_name") as! String
      print(userName)
})
```

I don't know what part the NSUserDefaults play but if the user is authenticated into Firebase, you should retrieve it from authData. If not and you've stored it in the NSUserDefaults, retrieve it from there instead of the authData.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `userId` out of scope, at the point where it does not exist, .
do something like this, keep firebase as optional property and then when you got userId create a url and then create `Firebase` Object with that URL.

```
let userAPI = "https://<myfirebase>.firebaseio.com/users/"
var firebase : Firebase?
var items = [NSDictionary]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let rightItemBtn = UIButton()
    rightItemBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    rightItemBtn.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 60, 35)


    let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let userID = (defaults.objectForKey("userID") as? String)!

    let url = "\(userAPI)\(userID)"
    firebase =  Firebase(url:url)


    let labelText = userID

    label.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 50, 35)

    label.text = labelText
}
```